# How to squash all migration files in to one in django?

Tags: django, django-migrations

I have 82 migration files in my django app. Some of them are related to removed models. I want to merge all these 82 migration files into one migration file.

How do I do without deleting the database?

Answer (score 11):

The [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/migrations/#migration-squashing) has a section devoted to this.

From the documentation page:

```sh
./manage.py squashmigrations myapp 0004
```

Where `myapp` is the name of your application, and `0004` is the migration to squash up to.

Comment: And dont forget to **make a backup before**.

Comment: @OlivierPons Why? Squashing migrations doesn't delete any files - it just creates a 'shortcut' migration that contains all of the steps you squashed.

Comment: A database backup. I dont remember why, but I know it's possible to make a mistake - I surely did. Not Django, but me. Just believe an old geek: it's much safer to always make a backup of everything: files and database. `;^)`

Comment: I agree that it safer - but this operation doesn't do anything to existing files or database. Sure, if you want to make a backup go ahead though... just wasn't sure that the bold was really justified in this instance.